# Thymeleaf support in IDEs

Tags: eclipse, spring-mvc, netbeans, intellij-idea, thymeleaf

The replacement of JSP by Thymeleaf in Spring is great! I like it very much. But library is new and IDEs are suffering lack of support of it. 
Can anyone suggest plugins or extensions for popular IDEs, such as Netbeans, Eclipse, IntelliJ, which supports syntax highlighting, autocomplete and error checking. Or does anybody know, may be this modules are in active development now?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is an official Thymeleaf plugin for eclipse: https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-eclipse-plugin

Support for IntelliJ IDEA has been requested and is a popular ticket now, but there are no news so far about any plans to really add it: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6713

*Disclaimer, due to StackOverflow rules: I am thymeleaf's author.*

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Daniel! Can you say is there any activity for making support in Netbeans?

Comment: @Demwis I don't know. If there is, I have no news about.

Comment: Current Status of 2014-08-05: "The Fix version field value (14) is the official response. It's on the roadmap for the next version, and we're working on it already. More details coming soon, please stay tuned."

Answer (score 4):

IntelliJ IDEA 14 is officially released with Thymeleaf support for code completion, navigation, finding usages, rename refactoring, 'Create message' quick-fix, and Spring MVC integration. 
For details see https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/whatsnew/